# Can we format JSON response in Android Network Profiler panel?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-profiler

I want to get formatted JSON response in Android Network Profiler rather than copy and paste to other tools to format JSON response.

Android Network Profiler is a convenient tool to inspect network traffic. But I can't read the response data immediately because our JSON data are shown in one line string.

Is there any way to get formatted JSON response in Android Network Profiler panel?

Comment: Open this link in browser: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. Now copy a single line response and paste into Json viewer.

Comment: @Ali I don't want to copy and paste.

Comment: you want to get directly on well format? @HvSimon

Comment: @Ali Yes, Network Profiler already know the response is JSON by Content Type. Why not format it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the new version Android Studio 3.3 provides new feature **View Parsed** in the profiler.

It can automatically format the response.

More infomation see [View formatted text for connection payloads in the Network profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/) section.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for like this

https://android.jlelse.eu/monitor-network-response-on-android-studio-39f572d8703b

Comment: Yes, but I can't find why he got formatted JSON. I use Android Studio 3.2.1. Maybe his JSON response didn't minify but I did?